# Unit1.guessanumber.inc(77) : Неизвестное имя 'guessanumber_Load'

Tags: pascal

Что делать с ошибкой постоянно вылезает.

```
procedure InitializeComponent;
    begin
        var resources: System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager := new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(guessanumber));
        self.textBox1 := new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        self.button1 := new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        self.label1 := new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        self.button2 := new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        self.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        self.textBox1.BackColor := System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowFrame;
        self.textBox1.BorderStyle := System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        self.textBox1.ForeColor := System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
        self.textBox1.Location := new System.Drawing.Point(12, 85);
        self.textBox1.Name := 'textBox1';
        self.textBox1.Size := new System.Drawing.Size(260, 20);
        self.textBox1.TabIndex := 0;
        self.textBox1.Tag := '';
        self.textBox1.TextAlign := System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        self.textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        self.button1.BackgroundImage := (System.Drawing.Image(resources.GetObject('button1.BackgroundImage')));
        self.button1.Cursor := System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
        self.button1.Image := (System.Drawing.Image(resources.GetObject('button1.Image')));
        self.button1.Location := new System.Drawing.Point(88, 128);
        self.button1.Name := 'button1';
        self.button1.Size := new System.Drawing.Size(101, 33);
        self.button1.TabIndex := 2;
        self.button1.Text := 'Проверить';
        self.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor := true;
        self.button1.Click += button1_Click;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        self.label1.BackColor := System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((System.Int32((System.Byte(0)))), (System.Int32((System.Byte(0)))), (System.Int32((System.Byte(0)))), (System.Int32((System.Byte(0)))));
        self.label1.ForeColor := System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
        self.label1.Location := new System.Drawing.Point(8, 28);
        self.label1.Name := 'label1';
        self.label1.Size := new System.Drawing.Size(272, 44);
        self.label1.TabIndex := 3;
        self.label1.Text := 'Игра угадай число Нажмите "Сгенерировать число", введите число и нажмите "Проверить"!';
        self.label1.TextAlign := System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        self.label1.Click += label1_Click;
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        self.button2.BackgroundImage := (System.Drawing.Image(resources.GetObject('button2.BackgroundImage')));
        self.button2.Cursor := System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
        self.button2.Image := (System.Drawing.Image(resources.GetObject('button2.Image')));
        self.button2.Location := new System.Drawing.Point(66, 178);
        self.button2.Name := 'button2';
        self.button2.Size := new System.Drawing.Size(145, 23);
        self.button2.TabIndex := 6;
        self.button2.Text := 'Сгенерировать число';
        self.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor := true;
        self.button2.Click += button2_Click;
        // 
        // guessanumber
        // 
        self.AutoScaleMode := System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
        self.AutoSize := true;
        self.AutoSizeMode := System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        self.BackColor := System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowFrame;
        self.BackgroundImage := (System.Drawing.Image(resources.GetObject('$this.BackgroundImage')));
        self.ClientSize := new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        self.Controls.Add(self.button2);
        self.Controls.Add(self.label1);
        self.Controls.Add(self.button1);
        self.Controls.Add(self.textBox1);
        self.Icon := (System.Drawing.Icon(resources.GetObject('$this.Icon')));
        self.Name := 'guessanumber';
        self.Text := 'Угадай число!';
        self.TransparencyKey := System.Drawing.SystemColors.GrayText;
        self.Load += guessanumber_Load;
        self.ResumeLayout(false);
        self.PerformLayout();
    end;
```